# Mupdf library on ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mupdf

A little question for some expert,it is possible to use mupdf library in a ionic app?works fine both on ios and android? otherwise any solutions?
I need to create an app to save data and use mupdf for digital sign.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will need a [Cordova plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) to interface between the mupdf core and your app.

From a quick check there seems to be one that covers iOS & Android here:

https://github.com/davearata/cordova-plugin-mupdf

I've no idea if it's any good. There's an alternative (Android only) here:

https://github.com/evandenberg/mupdf-viewer

Comment: thank you too much...yes there isn't nothing for ios

Comment: Hi i'll search in the library and there is a ios feature, but no one know something about ? i can't find anything like example or readme to use it.

Comment: @FabioBalsamo I think you need to rephrase that question and also include a link to whatever you've found, as I currently have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Hi...you're right.. so... i used that library https://github.com/davearata/cordova-plugin-mupdf
in ios, but there is no example or readme files to understand how use it.
The only method is pdf.openPdf(url,title,options,callback)
but there isn't other example of usage... i'll try to work around, but for me it's very difficult understand how use it in ios.